# add a new check to C# Executor file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm fairly new to C# and trying to add an additional check on an existing executor file. I added a new DTO to the existing file but i'm getting an empty/null object on the check which is causing a 500 Error with the message of

Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The call for reference is this:

```
if(currentDto.InvoiceId.HasValue && !userRoleDto.Role.Contains("Admin")){
   throw new BadRequestException("Only an admin can edit an invoiced work 
     order");
```

We want the userRoleDto.Role to be "Admin" which looks correct to me but i'm not sure if can introduce this other DTO in the same block as the workorderdto. I assumed we can use the var set up the same for userRoleDto.

```
namespace Domain.Data.WorkOrder.Commands;

public abstract class WorkOrderServiceUpdateExecutor<TCommand, TWorkOrder> : 
ICommandExecutor<DeltaWrapper<TCommand>>
   where TWorkOrder : Models.WorkOrder
   where TCommand : UpdateBasicWorkOrder
{
    private readonly IWorkOrderService _service;
    private readonly IUserService _userService; //ADDING USERSERVICE 
    private readonly IPatcher _patcher;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

protected WorkOrderServiceUpdateExecutor(
    IWorkOrderService service, IPatcher patcher, IMapper mapper)
{

    _service = service;
    _patcher = patcher;
    _mapper = mapper;
}

public async Task ExecuteAsync(DeltaWrapper<TCommand> deltaWrapper)
{
      
    var currentDto = await _service.GetFirstAsync(deltaWrapper.FilterSet ?? new 
    FilterSet()
    {
        [nameof(BaseEntity.OrganizationId)] = new 
     FilterValue(deltaWrapper.OrganizationId),
        [nameof(BaseEntity.Id)] = new FilterValue(deltaWrapper.Id)
    });
   var userRoleDto = await _userService.GetFirstAsync(deltaWrapper.FilterSet ?? new 
   FilterSet()
    {
        [nameof(BaseEntity.OrganizationId)] = new 
    FilterValue(deltaWrapper.OrganizationId),
        [nameof(BaseEntity.Id)] = new FilterValue(deltaWrapper.Id)
    });
    if(currentDto==null)
        throw new NotFoundException("not found");
    //if(currentDto.InvoiceId.HasValue && !userRoleDto.Role.Contains("Admin")){
       //throw new BadRequestException("Only an admin can edit an invoiced work 
     //order");
     }
    _patcher.Patch(currentDto, deltaWrapper);

    await _service.UpdateAsync(currentDto);

    var command = deltaWrapper.Command.OriginalCommand;
 }
}
```

Comment: `_userService` doesn't get initialized. You need to add it in the ctor injections and assign it.

Comment: within this file or in a Service file?

Comment: `private readonly IUserService _userService;` All the other private fields around this one get set in the Constructor of  `WorkOrderServiceUpdateExecutor`. Only this one does not. It will be `null`, therefore. Assuming it is set up in DI, all you need to do is analogue to the others: add a ctor argument and set the field to it in the ctor. Then it will be injected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an injection:

Your code does not initialize the `_userService` with an instance.

That why it will be `null` and any attempt in using it will fail with an Exception. You *may* even have a warning about this in your IDE.

If you change like this:

```
public abstract class WorkOrderServiceUpdateExecutor<TCommand, TWorkOrder> : 
ICommandExecutor<DeltaWrapper<TCommand>>
   where TWorkOrder : Models.WorkOrder
   where TCommand : UpdateBasicWorkOrder
{
    private readonly IWorkOrderService _service;
    private readonly IUserService _userService; //ADDING USERSERVICE 
    private readonly IPatcher _patcher;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    protected WorkOrderServiceUpdateExecutor(
        IWorkOrderService service, 
        IUserService userService, //ADDING USERSERVICE ALSO HERE !
        IPatcher patcher, 
        IMapper mapper)
    {
        _service = service;
        _userService = userService; // initialize the field!
        _patcher = patcher;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```

Then you should be good to go and use it.

| **Attention**: |
| --- |
| This is assuming you have it set up in your dependency injection configuration! |

Comment: Thank you!! totally didn't realize it wasn't in there!